# import Vue component and update content via axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, parsing, vue.js

I have two file, one is .js where is only registered vue component and in second i have template for vue with script. I want update information after click on some element, the data from axios i received, but i don't know how parse this data to array from which i want print data to template.

The code is [HERE](https://gist.github.com/TheNew1997/14f4879a2d99de85bd3c538a6fe0f071)

Error is: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentLog' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:

the problem was in function searchUser, when I save data into array after take it from axios via GET.

Replace "function" for "=>"

Right is [HERE](https://gist.github.com/TheNew1997/14f4879a2d99de85bd3c538a6fe0f071)

Answer (score 0):

That's because your searchUser function is outside of the vue instance therefore 'this' does not refer to it.
Try putting searchUser in methods, you will need to call it with this.searchUser then.

EDIT: your data definition is wrong, it should be:

```
data() {
        return {
            currentLog: {}
       }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but also not working, the same problem. Any other idea?

Comment: The function is call well, but can't save data to currentLog. When i write in this function `console.log(response.data);` data are printed

Comment: Thanks, and what I must write into searchUser when I moved it into methods? because when I have there `this.currentLog = response.data;` it's doing nothing

Comment: Why I can't save into array from method searchUser(), but from created() it's working?